# Compiler Error C2541 - 'delete' : delete : cannot delete objects that are not pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I wrote this class:

```
class StaticList
{
   private:
   int      headFree;
   int      headList;
   int      locNew;
   StaticListNode* listNodeArr;

   public:
   StaticList(int numberOfElements);
   ~StaticList();

   void addToStaticList(int ComputerNum);
   int getHeadList();
   int getHeadFree();
   StaticListNode* getListNodeArr();
   void show() const;
};
```

And I make a dynamic allocation:

```
StaticList::StaticList(int numberOfElements)
{
   headFree = 1; //Because the first headFree is 1 (the 0 cell is dummy)
   headList = -1;
   locNew = -1;

   this->listNodeArr = new StaticListNode[numberOfElements];

   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements - 1; i++) 
       listNodeArr[i].setNext(i + 1);

   listNodeArr[numberOfElements].setNext(-1);
}
```

> The problem is that when I try to delete the allocation through the d'tor, it gives me the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqHro.png)

what could be the problem? what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us `StaticListNode`'s members ?

Comment: `class StaticListNode`'s members are: int next, data.

Comment: Be sure you're using `delete[] this->listNodeArr;` in destructor, not just `delete this->listNodeArr`

Comment: Maybe `next` should have `StaticListNode*` type? Is it a link to the next node? In your implementation you must not call `delete` on `next`, because it is not a pointer

Comment: when you allocate for`numberOfElements` element `listNodeArr[numberOfElements].setNext(-1);` is a invalid place for you. change it to `[numberOfElements -1]`

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov I tried, it gives the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you allocate for n elements in array, `array[n]` is some place you don't access it.

when you call `delete` or `delete[]` it want to free somewhere of memory that it's not fom it.

so

```
listNodeArr[numberOfElements].setNext(-1);
```

is a invalid position in your array of class `StaticListNode`
change it to

```
listNodeArr[numberOfElements - 1].setNext(-1);
```

or whathever in correct place between `0` and `numberOfElements`